# Handling custom exception in ANTLR4

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr4

I have a grammar that parses URIs in the lexer and then constructs a java.net.URL from them in a grammar action.  The lexer can accept strings that might not be legal URLs so I'd like to intelligently handle URISyntaxExceptions if they get thrown.

I'm new to ANTLR 4 (but spent some time with ANTLR 3) and just want to know the best practice for handling such exceptions in 4.

Here's a code snippet from the grammar:

```
iri returns [IRI term] :
    IRIREF 
    { $term = spt.getIRI($IRIREF.text); } |
    prefixedName
    ;
```

'spt' is a support object I set with a parameter to the start rule.  The method 'getIRI' can throw the `java.net.URISyntaxException`.  I would like a graceful way to handle this locally in the rule, terminate the parse (or do something else), but don't know where to attach a catch block.

Comment: I too have experience with ANTLR3 (and almost none in ANTLR4) so I feel your pain. If you post code, and your current strategy then I can promise at least up-vote (if not any practical help). As is your question will probably be closed as too broad or primarily opinion based.

Comment: Thanks, Elliott.  I added a snippet.

Comment: Thought of another solution - I can mod the support object to throw a custom runtime exception and catch it outside the start production.  I'm not happy about it, but it will keep me going for now.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules#ParserRules-CatchingExceptions) covers the basics of catching errors and the implementation of error strategies.  The  [Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) covers both topics in much more detail.

Update:

The actual grammar specification (from ANTLRv4Parser.g4) for a 'rule' is

```
parserRuleSpec
  : DOC_COMMENT?
    ruleModifiers? RULE_REF ARG_ACTION?
    ruleReturns? throwsSpec? localsSpec?
    rulePrequel*
    COLON
    ruleBlock
    SEMI
    exceptionGroup
  ;
```

(In relevant part, this is the same as the 'rule' spec in ANTLRParser.g, which is the actual grammar used to build compiler tool present in the Antlr v4 jar.)

Comment: yup I tried that first.  Thing is the syntax in the docs is wrong.  It shows the catch clause coming after the rule terminator (;), which doesn't parse.  Placing it before the semicolon does parse.

Comment: When you say it does not parse, what error are you getting?  Is it giving any other errors or warnings?  If it is parsing with the catch block above the SEMI, check the generated code to see if it is attaching the catch to just the last alt of the rule.